# use of xanthan gum in tomato ketchup

Tags: sauce, thickening, cornstarch, ketchup, xanthan

If we make tomato ketchup of 100kg tomatoes.

- What would be the procedure to add the gum?
- What quantity of gum should be used?

Currently we are using corn starch as a thickener but it does not give the desired result.

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/84064/how-to-get-the-texture-of-commercial-ketchup?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Note that we are not a “service”, we are a community of people who enjoy cooking on various levels. I have removed all personal contact information from your post, all answers, should the community have some, will be posted right here below. Your question is also bordering on “too broad”. Please take the [tour] and browse our [help], especially [ask] to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: Hi, we can only deal with one question per post, or a few very closely related ones. You asked four. The fourth, about shelf stability, is unrelated to the other three. The first, "how to use", is mostly the same as the second about procedure. So I removed those and left only two, which makes it more answerable with a single post. Stephie's suggestion about reading the help center is very useful here.

Comment: Can you include a recipe and how thick you want the ketchup to be?

Answer (score 1):

Xanthan gum is a polysaccahride obtained through a fermentation process.  It is used to greatly reduce syneresis, stabilize emulsions, and to keep particles suspended in mixtures. It is "shear thinning", meaning that liquids with xanthan are viscous when at rest, but fluid when stirring. It has other culinary uses as well, but would be a good experiment your ketchup application.  You will want to add in a concentration of 0.7 - 1.5% of your total batch.  Be careful of using in a higher concentration, as xanthan can impart an undesirable, mucous-like texture if used too heavily.

Credit to Martin Lersch, and his terrific pdf called ["Texture: A Hydrocolloid Recipe Collection."](https://blog.khymos.org/recipe-collection/)